# Como repetir um bloco de programação em Python?

Tags: python, loop, pyautogui

Eu estou digitando uma automação em Python com a biblioteca `Pyautogui`.
Porém, como é algo repetitivo eu gostaria de repetir essa ação um determinado número de vezes.
Também importei a biblioteca `time` para dar uma pausa entre as ações.
O bloco de código que eu quero repetir é simples:

```
pg.click(x=430, y=17)
time.sleep(1)
pg.click(x=417, y=581)
time.sleep(1)
pg.click(x=477, y=539)
time.sleep(1)
pg.click(x=759, y=447)
```

Como eu realizo isso?
Estou utilizando o Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Crie uma lista com as coordenadas e faça um loop para percorrê-las: https://ideone.com/eBc7yn (nesse link o código não roda porque o IdeOne não carrega o módulo pyautogui, é só pra dar a ideia geral do código)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que a solução mais simples seja criar uma função para seu processamento e utilizar um loop para repeti-la quantas vezes for necessário, neste caso você poderia fazer destas maneiras:

1. Usando loop for:

```py
# main.py
NUMERO_DE_REPETICOES = 999

def funcao_para_repetir():
    print('Realizando algo que necessito repetir')
    
for numero in range(0, NUMERO_DE_REPETICOES):
    funcao_para_repetir()
```

2. Usando loop while:

```py
# main.py
NUMERO_DE_REPETICOES = 999

def funcao_para_repetir():
    print('Realizando algo que necessito repetir')
    
repeticao_atual = 0
while repeticao_atual != NUMERO_DE_REPETICOES:
    repeticao_atual += 1
    funcao_para_repetir()
```

Desta maneira você poderia começar as repetições via linha de comando com o python:

```bsh
python main.py
```